# Axios .get with headers fails in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, nuxtjs

axios.get with headers fails in production the header is not received on the backend.  everything works well in development. console log logs the  token on the front-end but undefined on the backend

```
//store action
verifyadmin({commit}, token){
      commit('setLoading', true)
      console.log(token)
      axios.get(`${url}/adminauth`,{headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'auth_token': token
        }})
        .then(data=>{
        console.log('admin auth', data);
        commit('setUser',token)
        commit('setLoading', false)
      }).catch(response=>{
        console.log(response,'erroree')
        commit('setLoading', false)
        commit('setErrorMessage', response)
      })
    },
```

//express api---------------Backend
this route verify the token

```
//verify 
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
module.exports = function authtoken(req,res,next){
    let token = req.header('auth_token')
    console.log(token)
    if (!token) res.status(401).json({error:'acess denied'})

    try{
        const tokenVerified = jwt.verify(token, 'procdesssenvTECRET')
        req.user=tokenVerified;
        next();
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({error:err, message:'Invalid token, access denied'})
    }
}
```

//router
the request fail at the first middlewear verify admin

```
//adminauth
const router = require('express').Router();
const cors = require('../allowCors');
const verify =require('../oathtoken');
const admin  =require('../isadmin');

router.route('/')
.options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); })
.get(cors.cors, verify, admin,(req,res)=>{
    try{
        res.status(200).json({user:req.user});
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(5000).json({message:'Server error, at admin verificationn'});
    }
})

module.exports= router;
```

Comment: might be the issue is related to the cors configuration

Comment: nginx/apache/proxy can cut some headers, check it first

Comment: thanks am using Nginx, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Nginx doesn't process headers with underscore 'auth_token' so I changed it to 'auth-toke'.